# Change the official language of Windows 7 as virtual machine

Tags: windows, vmware, virtualization, language

Someone just helped me install VMware Fusion on my Mac with Windows 7 as a virtual machine.

And I just realized that the official language is French, instead of English. Although I can read French, but I definitely prefer the whole system to be in English.

I don't think the “Region and Language” control panel is the right place to fix this, because I have already done as follows with English, which does not work:

[image]

Could anyone tell me if this setting is 100% dependent on what I settings I picked when I first installed Windows, or it this changeable?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot change this. Microsoft Windows exists in versions specific to languages and regions. If you have the French version of Windows 7 Professional, you cannot change its user interface language. You have to purchase a copy of the English version of Windows 7 Professional, delete your French copy, and make a new installation with the English version.

The alternative is to upgrade to Windows 7 Ultimate, which costs more money, and which can provide the user interface in different languages. The [Microsoft Windows 7 Version Comparison Chart](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/compare?t1=tab09) says that only Windows 7 Ultimate lets you "Work in the language of your choice and switch between any of 35 languages."

It goes without saying that Microsoft will only sell you Windows 7 Ultimate at the upgrade price if your copy of Windows 7 Professional is legally purchased and registered.